# Different tooltip and value in Treemap || Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, treemap

I am currently displaying a **treemap** with lot to data and hence due to huge values some tiles are taking more space compared to others.

So, I wanted to do a **log of value** and **show actual value** in tooltip.

But currently, i am give the tooltip from value attribute only.

Please suggest how to give **tooltip as well as value** simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `tooltip.formatter` function you are able to create any tooltip format, for example:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var str = this.point.name + ' ' + this.point.value,
                node = this.point.node;

            if (node) {
                node.children.forEach(function(child) {
                    str += '<br />' + child.name + ' ' + child.val;
                });
            }

            return str;
        }
    }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z5rdh83p/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: in the live demo, rick value is 10 under Banana group, can you assign rick value to 2 and still show 10 as value when hovered on rick?

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, Yes, just add some custom property to the data point: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cmpetk6z/